# Smartsheet API "There was an issue connecting"

Tags: http, smartsheet-api

When trying to create a new sheet with the C# SDK I get an error "Smartsheet.Api.Internal.Http.HttpClientException 'There was an issue connecting"

This is an Asp.net application in Visual Studio 2019 using IIS Express.

It worked fine when writing this as a windows application. Assuming it has something to do with the proxy/security settings of IIS then.

target framework is 4.6.1
Smartsheet SDK 2.6
RestSharp 106.6.9
Nlog 4.5.3
NewtonSoft 12.02

Comment: Jordan is this always reproducible, or just occasionally?

Comment: It happens every time.

Comment: Sorry Jordan, and you said you are using a proxy? RestSharp may be picking up the system proxy settings for the Windows client but not on IIS. You can force it to use a proxy using the sample code here: https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-csharp-sdk/blob/master/ADVANCED.md#sample-proxyhttpclient

Comment: Hi tim. I had looked at this code and tried to implement it. So when I tried this code it gave the same failure but it did fail faster lol. I passed in “localhost” and then my port number.